# Want to center my horizontal navigation

Tags: html, css, tabs, nav

I have a horizontal navigation with curved tabs. I want to center my horizontal navigation relative to whatever the screen resolution is. Currently, my horizontal nav is 260px away from the left hand margin. So instead of this way, just want to make it centered to the screen regardless of screen resolution.

**base_menu.html**

```
<ul id="toc">
        <li><a href="{% url mmc.views.return_clients %}"><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url mmc.views.quote_step1 %}"><span>Create quote/order</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url mmc.views.search_item %}"><span> Item Search</span></a></li>
        <li><a><span>Service orders</span></a><br/>
        <ul class="subnav">
                <li><a href="{% url mmc.views.order_list %}"><span>Storage orders</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url mmc.views.order_list_service 1 %}"><span>Delivery orders</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url mmc.views.order_list_service 2 %}"><span>Collection orders</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a><span>Collection/Delivery</span></a><br/>
        <ul class="subnav">
                <li><a href="{% url mmc.views.service_list 1 %}"><span>Delivery list</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url mmc.views.service_list 2 %}"><span>Collection list</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a><span>Admin Tools</span></a><br/>
        <ul class="subnav">
                <li><a href="{% url mmc.views.invoice_list %}"><span>Export for invoicing</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url mmc.views.dbbackup %}"><span>Backup data</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="{% url mmc.views.help_login %}" target="_blank" onclick="return showAddAnotherPopup(this);"><span>Help</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

**base.css**

```
ul#toc {
    height: 2em;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 260px;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}


ul#toc li{
    background:#ffffff url(../images/tab.png);
    float: left;
    margin: 0 1px 0 0;

}

ul#toc li#drop{
    background-color:#bce6c3;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 1px 0 0;

}
ul#toc span {
    background: url(../images/tab.png) 100% 0;
    display: block;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

ul#toc a {
    color: #000000;
    height: 2em;
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 10px;
}


ul#toc a:hover {
    background: url(../images/tab2.png);
    text-decoration: underline;
}

ul#toc a:hover  span{
    background: url(../images/tab2.png) 100% 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the margin rule for your ul in your css like so:

```
ul#toc{
     margin: 0 auto;}
```

This makes the browser automatically equal the margin either side of your ul element.

Also you need to give your ul#toc a fixed width as with a width of 100% it cannot center anything as it fits the whole width of the screen.

Comment: `@NVTOnline:` I removed `margin-left: 260px;` and added `margin: 0 auto;` but it did not work. It has moved my horizontal navigation to the left side of the screen.

Comment: You need to also add a fixed width to ul#toc, e.g 500px.

Comment: Change the width of your element also, with a width of 100% it cannot center anything as it fits the screen. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: `@james6848:`Currently my width is sent to 100%. So I need to set up as  a fixed width. In this case my horizontal nav is quiet long so what do you think is ideal? 1000px?

Comment: Why not measure it with a pixel ruler, search for one on google, there are plenty free to use, also if you use chrome you can download apps for it too.